# How Would You Tackle This? Email Design Where Image Overlaps 2 Solid Colors

Tags: html-email, marketo

I develop module-based email templates in Marketo with Marketo 2.0 syntax.

My client designed a fancy looking module where an image is overlapping 2 solid colors. If it were web design, no problem, but for email, not sure how to do this.
My only good idea is to do a table with row and column spans. Anything better out there? Do you think negative margins will work in email?

What they are asking it to look like:

[image]

My lines showing how i'd build a table to support it:

[image]

Comment: You can try VML if you havent. There was an article written by Mark Robbins https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good way forward (to use tables). Negative margins don't have great support.

You also cannot rely on colspan and rowspan because Outlook desktops on Windows don't support them. However, all you need to do for the section where you would use that is to nest a table.

I.e. instead of this for the middle section:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="xxx">&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="xxx">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

You would need to have one row like this:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="xxx">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="xxx">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fake absolute positioning and then use VML for Outlook support, see Steven Sayo's awesome [Overlay & Email Absolute Positioning](https://medium.com/@sayo1337/overlay-email-absolute-positioning-efd2f2f09ed4) tutorial.